# Where in MCU canon is the 'Team Thor' mockumentary?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, team-thor

I've just seen the [Mocumentary](https://twitter.com/MarvelStudios/status/769927705651392513/video/1) 'Team Thor'.

I can't tell how seriously to take this; it shows Thor tucking Mjolnir into a mini bed, but it also shows a pin board of connections between lots of important events in the Marvel universe.

Did this really happen in the MCU, or should I take it with a pinch of salt?

Comment: *Pinch* of salt? Perhaps you just don't get the humour but **of course** it's not meant to be taken seriously. It's just a bit of comedy which "explains" why Thor and the Hulk weren't in Civil War.

Comment: They do this all the time in MCU. Their signature is to share the story with a sense of humor that entertains people. I don't think Thor spent his time with an Earthling. As always, they made Thor into a witless giant but let's not forget he is the protector of the Nine Realms and wielder of Mjolnir.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Based on [*Thor: Ragnarok*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok), *Team Thor* is likely non-canon.**

According to *Thor: Ragnarok*, Bruce Banner has been off-planet in Hulk form for the past 2 years, making it impossible for Bruce and Thor to have the conversation shown in the *Team Thor* short. We also see that Bruce Banner has no memory of any events taking place after *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Thor's roommate Darryl *does* show up again in the Ragnarok short *Team Darryl*, but similar to *Team Thor*, it probably shouldn't be considered cannon.

Comment: Of course, in *Thor: Ragnarok*, we do see Thor visit earth, and the Sanctum Santorum, where he meets Doctor Strange. It’s possible that his time with Daryl occurred thanks to an intervention by magic and/or the Time Stone, and that he merely hallucinated the entire conversation with Banner as a side-effect of all that sorcery.

Comment: I think most of the "extras" on the DVDs may be considered non-canon.  Several of them are contradicted by later productions - Peggy Carter's short is clearly overwritten by her TV show, for example, and any suggestion that there's a real Mandarin has been largely ignored in later films.

Comment: While we naturally assume Banner and Thor are referring to Civil War events - it really could be deceptive editing.  We really don't know what fight Captain America and Tony Stark are having that Thor is not invited to and Banner is declining to join.  It could be a Munsters vs. Addams family debate for all we know.  So if we assume that Team Thor scene was filmed just prior to age of Ultron it could still be canon.  Documentaries can film things out of order.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's safe to assume that the *Team Thor* short is non-canon.

As far as we know, nobody knows where Bruce Banner and Thor are by the time of *Captain America: Civil War*. They've gone AWOL - Secretary of State Ross specifically mentions this in *Captain America: Civil War* while talking to the Avengers;

> "Tell me, Captain, do you know where Thor and Banner are right now? 'Cause you can bet if I misplaced a couple of 30 megaton warheads, there'd be consequences."
>
> <sup>Secretary of State Thaddeus Ross, *Captain America: Civil War*</sup>

This obviously goes against what we see in the *Team Thor* short, with Bruce Banner being in contact with Tony Stark and Thor having Darryl email Steve Rogers for him.

Ultimately, we won't know for sure about the canonicity of *Team Thor* until *Thor: Ragnarok* is released, but I feel pretty confident in saying that the third Thor film will "disprove" this short.

Comment: More's the point, Thor is a pretty recognisable guy. Wherever he was, it wasn't in downtown Adelaide in full armour.

Comment: You're probably right, but... I don't remember where in the movie that scene with Ross occurred, but it could have been before Thor tried contacting them, and even if it isn't, I wouldn't put it past Tony to hide that he knows how to contact Banner.

Comment: While these are lines from the movies, Cap doesn't reply, so it's possible (if unlikely) that he DOES know.

Answer (score 2):

### It is canon, and Darryl will "probably" appear again.

Taika Waititi, the director of Thor: Ragnarok, elaborated on the team thor mockumentary in [a recent interview wih IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/09/16/is-thors-roommate-in-ragnarok).

> Thor briefly rented a room in a flat in Australia after the Ultron debacle. Just to get some downtime – to get away from The Avengers, to get away from America. So he had a little downtime in Australian. And he met this guy Darryl and they shared a flat together. So that’s Darryl.
>
> I think you probably could see him again. There may be other little pieces of that thing that everyone saw that may just be a small part of a bigger thing.

Comment: I'm having a hard time telling if Waititi is being serious or if he is just keeping the joke going.

Comment: @Thunderforge I wouldn't put it past Taika.