# Does a complete image of Thor's pinboard exist?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, team-thor

In the mockumentary [Team Thor](https://twitter.com/MarvelStudios/status/769927705651392513/video/1), Thor has a pinboard of various connections in the marvel universe, including this hilarious image of

> Thanos
>  [image: Thanos drawing]

Where can I find a copy of the whole board, regardless of its [canonicity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139061/3804)?

Comment: In the absence of an official image of the full board, here's one that someone stitched together from screencaps: http://i.imgur.com/PncVDl2.jpg